# Can I set the "In-Reply-To" header when using the Linux mail command?

Tags: command-line-interface, email

I thought I could use:

```
mail -s "Subject_here" -a "In-Reply-To: Message_ID_here" < body
```

but unfortunately the `-a` is unrecognised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this way of using `sendmail` instead:

```
/usr/lib/sendmail -t < body
```

The file `body` should have each header on a separate line, then a blank line, then your message body text:

```
To: bob@example.com
From: tim@example.com
Subject: Example of conversation threading
In-reply-to: <put Message-ID of previous mail here>

Body text here
```

Answer (score 1):

I think -a for additional header does not work in case you mail command is Heirloom mailx. In Heirloom mailx -a flag is for file attachment. As you answered to yourself, you can use sendmail, but you can also use -t flag to Heirloom mailx, too.

```
mail -t < body
```

The body text is same as that of your own answer.

```
To: bob@example.com
From: tim@example.com
Subject: Example of conversation threading
In-Reply-To: <put Message-ID of previous mail here>

Body text here
```

This worked for me.